# Attaching a 2 x 4 to a door frame

Tags: doors, door-frame, addition

I am trying to find a way to add a pullup bar to my home gym. Ordinarily the pullup bar contraption goes over and through the door frame, but the door frames we have go all the way up to the ceiling so this does not work. I am looking for a way to add a 2 x 4 or something similar to the door frame in order to make this work. Obviously I have no clue how to do this. As I am a renter I do not want to cut out a piece of the door frame in order to notch the bar (or 2 x 4) in. Does anyone have any recommendations on what I should do? Note the door does not actually close so I would entertain anything up to and including the removal of the door.

I googled online and cannot find anything that gives me any ideas.

Example pull up 
https://www.target.com/p/perfect-fitness-multi-gym/-/A-79786741?ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&fndsrc=tgtao&CPNG=PLA_Sports%2BShopping&adgroup=SC_Sports&LID=700000001170770pgs&network=g&device=c&location=9003433&ds_rl=1246978&ds_rl=1248099&ds_rl=1246978&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIne6EzqXI6AIVxZ6zCh3WdQ69EAQYAyABEgI3lvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: The pull up bar you cited indicates ir securely fits doorframes up to 35" wide and 6" deep. Doesn't that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

How about a bar that fastens to the door frame? See below. Two knobs screw into the door frame and the adjustable bar fits over them.

[image]

https://www.wish.com/product/55f7ec5f74135f27949f81f3?from_ad=goog_shopping&_display_country_code=US&_force_currency_code=USD&pid=googleadwords_int&c=%7BcampaignId%7D&ad_cid=55f7ec5f74135f27949f81f3&ad_cc=US&ad_curr=USD&ad_price=13.00&campaign_id=7203534630&gclid=CjwKCAjw95D0BRBFEiwAcO1KDHImYeLqPzXFHZlrqodUTA905VhaDoh9enymz1sFbED6Ia14VsjuPRoCv-MQAvD_BwE&hide_login_modal=true&share=web

Or just get two 1" pipe flanges and the appropriate length of threaded 1" pipe. Screw the flanges on to each end of the pipe and screw them into the door frame.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I like this suggestion.

Comment: This is what I used and it works great for pull ups. Also for throwing wet clothes over to dry! And for coat hangers while ironing

Answer (score 0):

Zip tie a 2x4 to the pull up bar to the two ends on the far side of the door that would normally hit the top of the door frame. Put the 2x4 closer to the door, the zip ties are only there to keep things held together, not to take the force of bar. The 2x4 would be as wide as the other part of the pull bar that hits the near side of the door frame. This will change the angle of the part you use to pull up on but it shouldn't be enough to cause problems. This way, it's always with your pull up bar and not unsightly mounted to your door frame. Note that the whole rig probably will not stay in place like before and slide down without downward pressure on the part you used to do your pull-ups, since the weight of the 2x4 changes the weight balance.

Comment: Thank you let me try that.